# Segmented control in tableCell

Tags: ios, swift, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a problem with segmented control in table cell. No action of Segmented control

```
segmentedFilter.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ProductListFilterCell.filterSelected), forControlEvents: .AllEvents)
```

Target function:

```
func filterSelected() {
    if let order = ProductListViewModel.OrderBy(rawValue: segmentedFilter.selectedSegmentIndex), let change = orderChanged{
        change(order)
    }
}
```

Is it possible to have segmented control in table cell ?

Comment: What method performs the call to `addTarget`? Do you use a storyboard/NIB, or creating your cell programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

It is incorrect to call `addTarget` in `prepareForReuse`, because this method is called when the cell is no longer needed. Only reused cells would have a selector on them.

The second problem is the target: you are passing `self`, which is the data source for the table, but the selector refers to the cell. If you bring up a reused cell by scrolling up and down several times, your control would trigger the event, and the app would crash with unknown selector message.

You can fix this by moving the method into the data source class, adding target in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, and removing the target in `prepareForReuse`.

```
segmentedFilter.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ProductListDataSource.filterSelected), forControlEvents: .AllEvents)
//                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: I add `cellFilter.segmentedFilter.addTarget(self, action: #selector(MainTableView.filterSelected(_:)), forControlEvents: .AllEvents)` to `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and still not working :(